Request for Sepolia Test ETH
I'm a developer working on a project and I need some Sepolia test ETH to continue testing my smart contract. Could anyone please help me by sending some test ETH to my address?
Here’s my Sepolia address:
0x4F382eC35477a8273953471E3b5f6b36201Ea096
Thank you so much for your help!
Best regards,
Gedas

You can find Sepolia ETH at any online faucet. Here's a trusted faucet by Alchemy: https://www.alchemy.com/faucets/ethereum-sepolia
